# Xamarin - Cannot install NuGet packages correctly because version conflict

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android, nuget-package

I'm using `MSVS2015 Pro` with `Xamarin`.

I just downloaded the `Xamarin-Evolve` package from `GitHub`.
Then I tried to install the required NuGet package: `HockeySDK` but I'm getting a version conflict. It says: `Could not install package 'HockeySDK.Core 4.1.5'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'MonoAndroid,Version=v6.0', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework.`

As you can see on the following image:

[image]

Then I would like to know:

1. where on the `NuGet.org` page, I can find a relationship between a `nuget package` and the target versions?
2. By the way, how to solve the issue below?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the target platforms are extracted from the package and mentioned on the NuGet.org page. There is a `Dependencies` section but as far as I know it contains only the information the developer decided to manually enter. It is quite common to include the target platform in the package name, as is the case here. You seem to be attempting to install a UWP package in an Android project. Have you tried the [Xamarin version of the package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HockeySDK.Xamarin/)?

When you download the package you can open it as a .zip archive - the `lib` directory in that archive contains the target platforms. In the end that's how the NuGet installer is able to tell whether the package is compatible with your project ([source](https://docs.nuget.org/ndocs/create-packages/supporting-multiple-target-frameworks)).

Answer (score 0):

Nuget does not *currently* provide a way to search/filter by target/framework:

- https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/3156
- https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/2084

You are installing `HockeySDK.UWP` into a `Xamarin.Android` project, you would want the following package:

```
`HockeySDK.Xamarin`
```